# Is it possible to make w the subject of this equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I have a differential equation which models a specific diet.

$\frac{dw}{dt} = -{w}^3 - {w}^2$ (leaving out constants for simplicity)

Wolfram Alpha tells me the solution is:

$log(w+1) - log(w) - \frac{1}{w} 
 = c - t$

Is it possible to rearrange this to make w the subject of the equation?

Comment: Do you have any experience with differential equations? This one is separable.

Comment: Do you mean you want to solve the equation for $w$ in terms of $t$? I would say probably unlikely. WolframAlpha does not give a solution: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+log(w%2B1)-log(w)-1%2Fw%3Dc-t+for+w

Comment: Yeah - it is separable. You separate it and then use partial fractions and I'm sure you'll get the same solution that wolfram alpha generated...

Comment: @Rahul - yes exactly. Ahhh I see, thats a bummer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\log(w+1) - \log(w) - \frac{1}{w}  = c - t \\
\implies\log\left(\left(1+\frac{1}{w}\right)\exp\left(-\left(1+\frac{1}{w}\right)\right)\right)=c-1-t$$

Let $v=-\left(1+\frac{1}{w}\right)$, then

$$\implies -v\exp(v)=\exp(c-1-t) \\
\implies v\exp(v)=-\exp(c-1-t) \\
\implies\text{Lambert_W}(-\exp(c-1-t))=v \\
\implies w=\frac{-1}{1+v}=\frac{-1}{1+\text{Lambert_W}(-\exp(c-1-t))}$$